# Display validation errors in the same style as cripsy error messages

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I'm using crispy forms to make my forms look nice and added the following validation:

forms.py

```
class Meta:
    widgets = {
            'dob': DatePickerInput(
                options={
                    "format": "MM/DD/YYYY",
                    "showClose": False,
                    "showClear": False,
                    "showTodayButton": False,
                }
            ),
    }

def clean(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        born = data.get('dob')
        today = date.today()
        age = (today.year - born.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (born.month, born.day)))

        if age < 14:
            msg = ("Sorry, you must be atleast 14 years old")
            self.add_error('dob', msg)

        if age > 110:
            msg = ("You entered a date of birth outside of the accepted range. Please try again.")
            self.add_error('dob', msg)

        return data
```

models.py

```
dob = models.DateTimeField('Date of birth (mm/dd/yyyy)', null=True, default=now)
```

My problem is that this error message displays at the top of the page as a flash message, while other messages (which i did not set but are built into crispy, such as when a user leaves a required field blank) are displayed as a pop up message box under the field the errors related to.

I am wondering how I can make my added validation error appear the same as other in-built crispy error messages, for consistency.

Image - (https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkTUT.jpg)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are overriding clean method then you can use [add_error()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other):

```
def clean(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data
    age = data.get("age")

    if age < 14:
        msg = "Sorry, you must be atleast 14 years old to study with IPC IELTS."
        self.add_error('age', msg)

    if age > 110:
        msg = "You entered a date of birth outside of the accepted range. Please try again."
        self.add_error('age', msg)

    return data
```

You can also put validation on your Model or on Form:

```
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator,MaxValueValidator
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class YourModel(models.Model):
    age = models.DecimalField(..., validators=[
        MinValueValidator(14, message=_("Sorry, you must be atleast 
            14 years old to study with IPC IELTS.")),
        MaxValueValidator(110, message=_("You entered a date of birth outside of the 
            accepted range. Please try again."))
    ])
```

So that you don't need to style it manually for that field.

Comment: Thank you so much :) That now turns the field red, but it doesn't display the error message :(
I edited my post to give more information

Comment: Ok, The error is not showing up because of `DatePickerInput` I guess. It works with default `DateTimeField` I just checked. Can you provide `DatePickerInput` link.

Comment: Sure. https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus/

Comment: Also, is it possible to have the error appear the same as the error in the field 'gender' in this img please? https://imgur.com/VQHMKUp

Comment: Yes, it is possible however you have to write some JavaScript function for it.

Comment: Ahh okay.
I will give it a try.
This is it isn't it? https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/crispy_tag_forms.html#ajax-validation-recipe
Thanks again :)

Comment: Yes, give it a try. : )

Comment: Great. Thanks again. I appreciate it:)